# Zero-padding array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, embedded, padding

I have a uint8_t array, containing three bytes.

```
// 1010 1010 1011 1011 1000 0000
uint8_t command[3] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0x80};
```

I now want to zero-pad the array with 7 zeroes on the left side, eventually creating the following array (the 4th byte is of no interest to me):

```
// 0000 0001 0101 0101 0111 0111 0000 0000
uint8_t expected_output[4] = {0x01, 0x55, 0x77, 0x00};
```

What's the best way to get this zero-padding implemented in C++ ?

Comment: Take a look at [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: c is not c++ and c++ is not c, I removed the tag

Comment: Thanks @Evg, I'll have a look at the documentation. I just want a reliable way that doesn't depend on little/big endian architecture.

Comment: If endianness is a matter, what exactly do you want to do? If you use the array internally only, then I'd go with one large `uint32_t` instead. Any endianess matters are gone. If you need to transfer via network, the array as is is just fine, you have four single bytes, so endianess is no issue, and you just need to place them in correct order. If you want to use the value/array for *both*, then you have contradicting requirements and you *will* have to deal with endianess in some way (functions like [htole32](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htobe64) or ntohl just hide that away...).

Comment: A `uint8_t [4]` will always depend on endianess, because it will always store the data from LS `0x01, 0x55, 0x77, 0x00` MS. That's consistent with Big Endian 32 bit numbers. But if you want this to equal the 32 bit number 0x01557700 then it is not consistent any longer and won't work on Little Endian machines.

Comment: That is, you can do `std::bitset<32> bs (0xAABB8000); bs>>=7;` and it will be as efficient as C code, but when you want to interpret this as a 32 bit number you are stuck with endianess dependencies.

Comment: Is there a reliable way to convert a bitset to a uint8_t array? I have my bitset<24> all set up and shifted as required, but the library function expects a uint8_t array as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using `std::bitset`:

```
std::array<std::uint8_t, 4>
left_pad(const std::array<std::uint8_t, 3>& in) {
    using Bitset = std::bitset<8 * 4>;
    Bitset bitset;

    for (auto b = in.begin(); b != in.end(); ++b, bitset <<= 8)
        bitset |= Bitset{*b};
    bitset >>= 7;

    std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> out;
    for (auto b = out.rbegin(); b != out.rend(); ++b, bitset >>= 8)
        *b = (bitset & Bitset{0xFF}).to_ulong();

    return out;
}
```

And then:

```
void foo(std::uint8_t[4]);

void bar() {
    std::array<std::uint8_t, 3> command{0xCA, 0xBB, 0x80};
    std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> out = left_pad(command);
    foo(out.data());
}
```

If the input length is fixed to 3 bytes and no generalization for larger lengths is needed, `std::bitset<8 * 4>` can be replaced with `std::uint32_t`.

**Addition after discussion in comments.**

This equivalent version

```
std::array<std::uint8_t, 4>
left_pad2(const std::array<std::uint8_t, 3>& in) {
    using Bitset = std::bitset<8 * 4>;
    Bitset bitset;

    for (auto b = in.begin(); b != in.end(); ++b) {
        bitset <<= 8;
        bitset |= Bitset{*b};
    }
    bitset <<= 1;

    std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> out;
    for (auto b = out.rbegin(); b != out.rend(); ++b, bitset >>= 8)
        *b = (bitset & Bitset{0xFF}).to_ulong();

    return out;
}
```

gives [better assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/6jSW38) with GCC and `-O3` optimization:

```
left_pad2(std::array<unsigned char, 3ul> const&):
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rdi+1]
        sal     rax, 8
        or      rax, rdx
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rdi+2]
        sal     rax, 8
        or      rax, rdx
        add     rax, rax
        bswap   eax
        ret
```

versus

```
left_pad(std::array<unsigned char, 3ul> const&):
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rdi+1]
        sal     rax, 8
        or      rax, rdx
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rdi+2]
        sal     rax, 8
        or      rax, rdx
        sal     rax, 8
        mov     rdx, rax
        shr     rdx, 7
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp-1], dl
        mov     rdx, rax
        shr     rdx, 15
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp-2], dl
        mov     rdx, rax
        shr     rax, 31
        shr     rdx, 23
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp-4], al
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp-3], dl
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        ret
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I just tried to debug through the code. When inserting command = `0b0000.0000.1111.1111.1000.0000` (0x00 0xFF 0x80) I get the output `0b0000.0000.0000.0001.1111.1111.0000.0000`(0x00 0x01 0xFF 0x00). I expected the last byte to be 0x80 instead of 0x00 (1 in the MSB).

Comment: @Lexusminds, it's not clear why it should be `0x80`. What is the expected output for `{0x12, 0x34, 0x56}`?

Comment: Maybe I should talk about the root cause: I'm using a library to calculate a CRC-7 on 17 bits. These 17 bits consist of 8 data bits, 8 command bits and a const '1'. Since the library takes char arrays as its input, I need to convert the 17 bits into a zero-padded 24 bits (3 byte) array. So it is crucial to preserve all 17 bits, including the '1'.

Comment: Oh, you're right - the output is as expected. I'm sorry - shouldn't do bitwise calculations right after lunch.

Comment: There should be no need to write the initial values to the bitset in run-time.

Comment: @Lundin, you mean the first `for` loop?

Comment: Yes. I take it that the default constructor for bitset too awkward for arrays?

Comment: @Lundin, [`bitset` constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) either take `unsigned long long` or `std::string` of 0s and 1s. I found no better way to construct a bitset than using a raw `for` loop.

Comment: Perfect reason not to use `bitset` I guess. Plain old C already solves this perfectly. We can unf** C++11 with a macro though: `#define THIS_IS_BS(b0,b1,b2,b3) 0x##b0##b1#b2##b3`. Usage: `std::bitset<32> bs (THIS_IS_BS(AA,BB,80,00));` Clearly an improvement over `typedef union { uint8_t bytes[4]; uint32_t u32; } foo; ... foo f = {.bytes={0xAA, 0xBB, 0x80, 0x00}};`, right?

Comment: @Lundin, I don't know about C, but in C++ type punning through a union is UB by the standard. `for` loops and `bitset` are likely to be [optimized out completely](https://godbolt.org/z/D_HTpe), anyway.

Comment: @Evg That's exactly my point. C is superior here because it allows type punning. No, the for loops are not optimized out. https://godbolt.org/z/PXbH9T. `-O3` unrolls the loop but it's still rather bad machine code.

Comment: @Lundin, yeah, agree. `-Os` was the wrong option. But if input is known at compile-time, the compiler can [calculate the output at compile-time](https://godbolt.org/z/k9RvZb), too.

Comment: Yeah but they might exist in different translation units. So it seems you have to use the BS macro to initialize a `bitset` from an array of bytes...

Comment: @Lundin, if bytes are known at compile-time.